# How to read json data in Python that received the json data from sns

Tags: python, json, lambda, aws-lambda

This is the json data I am receiving from aws sns notifications. I want to access `deploymentGroupName`  which is inside the `Records->Sns->Message`

In my lambda python code I am trying to do like this.

```
eventName = json.loads(event.Records[0].Sns.Message).deploymentGroupName;
```

This is the json I received.

```
{
    'Records': [{
        'EventSource': 'aws:sns',
        'EventVersion': '1.0',
        'EventSubscriptionArn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:1236542:project-Deploy-Success:123-654-12-b177-123654',
        'Sns': {
            'Type': 'Notification',
            'MessageId': '6ef313fa-46d2-5841-b162-4805edfb421c',
            'TopicArn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:428219256379:project-Deploy-Success',
            'Subject': 'SUCCEEDED: AWS CodeDeploy d-E8BYQ65CL in us-east-1 to project-code-deploy',
            'Message': '{"region":"us-east-1","accountId":"213321213321","eventTriggerName":"Sandbox-Deployment-Triggered","applicationName":"project-code-deploy","deploymentId":"d-E8BYQ65CL","deploymentGroupName":"Sandbox-ec2-deployment","createTime":"Tue Nov 29 06:38:20 UTC 2022","completeTime":"Tue Nov 29 06:38:33 UTC 2022","deploymentOverview":"{\\"Succeeded\\":1,\\"Failed\\":0,\\"Skipped\\":0,\\"InProgress\\":0,\\"Pending\\":0}","status":"SUCCEEDED"}',
            'Timestamp': '2022-11-29T06:38:33.558Z',
        }
    }]
}
```

Right now giving this error.

> [ERROR] NameError: name 'json' is not defined
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 12, in lambda_handler
> eventName = json.loads(event.Records[0].Sns.Message).deploymentGroupName;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `event` has no `""` surrounding, it has converted to `dict` already. However, you need to deal with `json` for `Message`.

```
import json

msg = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
deploymentGroupName = json.loads(msg)['deploymentGroupName']
deploymentGroupName
```

output:

```
'Sandbox-ec2-deployment'
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine. Yes it has not `""` surrounding.